# How to have AngularJS router update a controller value upon navigation, rather than reloading the entire controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a large and complex view that is served on a route like `/dailyReport/:dayId`

When a user is navigating between different daily reports, I'd like to just update the `DailyReportController` with the new `dayId` rather than reloading the whole controller.

How can I do that?

Comment: How about moving the controller to parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$location.search()` and `reloadOnSearch: false` and then pass the dayId in the query string:

```
.when('/dailyReport', {
    templateUrl: 'view.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

To get notified on dayId change:

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(){
  console.log($location.search().dayId);
});
```

Then to link to a new day:

```
<a href="#/dailyReport?dayId=2">Change day to 2</a>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A1A8eKg6og60Xl95R4tA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Wayne's answer is probably the simplest but it has the disadvantage of making your routes a little obscure.

Another approach would be to move the state, on which your view depends, from your controller/scope (instantiated for each navigation) to a service (singleton) that exposes a `setDay()` method. The controller would then take a dependency on the service, and simply call `setDay()` on each activation.